# One word for an unforeseen bad dream

Tags: single-word-requests

Consider the passage:

> The IT industry has come a long way from the time it started. In not even a hundred years, we have seen dreams — like robots — come true. But we have also seen the [unforeseen bad dream?] — viruses.

I want a good word to place in the brackets — like a word which means an "unforeseen bad dream" — or some other word which better fits the context.

Comment: Do you mean an unpredicted bad dream? Or a disturbing dream?

Comment: @ThirdNews unpredicted bad dream - yes that's what I mean.

Comment: Please clarify how a dream can be unseen, especially if we have expressly *seen* it.

Comment: @RegDwigнt When the IT industry started, nobody had predicted that there would be viruses (a bad dream) - had anyone ?

Comment: Then you mean *unforeseen*. That is a completely different word. I have edited the question accordingly. Likewise, please do not use hyphens instead of dashes. They do not mean the same thing.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Ok, I did not know there is a difference. But I don't know if keyboards have a hyphen sign. I don't have one on mine.

Comment: @ermanen The word looks good. But how do I use it in my passage? It would break the flow I think. Consider "we have also seen the latent viruses" ? I want to make it sound sort of evil.

Comment: The dream definition is throwing me but 'vagary' is otherwise perfect. Vagary: "an unpredictable or erratic action, occurrence, course, or instance"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say:

But we have also seen the *unexpected* **evils** , like viruses.

Comment: I'd remove *the*

Comment: How about **unsuspected** instead: _"not known or thought to exist or be present; not imagined possible."_ The word **unexpected** does not resonate with the moral aspect, as it is  more related to likelihood and probability, making it neutral.

Answer (score 6):

You can use *nightmare* to fill the blank. But since the word *unseen* is associated,

> An unaccounted nightmare

Comment: Well, that would be sort of "too heavy" word - I am going to use this passage in my project, so, is there sort of a "light word" ?

Comment: IMO Nightmare is a very common word , but if you feel its heavy then Josh's "unexpected evils" is pretty accurate as well!

Comment: **unaccounted** is not a good synonym for **unforeseen**. The first means _"Something, after it happened, can not be explained"_ while the second is for _"Not felt or realized beforehand"_.

Answer (score 2):

What about *nightmares*? Not exactly “unseen”, but I am not really sure what you mean with that.

The contrast between *dreams* (usually implied **good**) and *nightmares* (always **bad** dreams) is commonly used, and would certainly fit in this context.

Comment: Yeah , when I read the question second time , I came to that conclusion and made necessary changes. I thought the OP just needed a synonym for bad dream..

And dream is not usually implied as 'good' it is nuetral.A good dream would be a 'fantasy'

Comment: _Dream_ on its own is neutral, true. But when juxtaposing it to a nightmare, the _good_ is implied quite clearly :)

Answer (score 1):

How about *phantasm* for a more interesting word?

Comment: I like the word *phantasm* but its strongest connotation is "illusion," which is not appropriate to the request.

Answer (score 1):

How about *perverse consequences*?

Answer (score 1):

"But we have also seen the emergence of an unanticipated spectre -- the virus problem."

Answer (score 0):

How about *darkness*. 
Seems like it might fit if nightmare is too heavy. It may be a slightly odd relation to dream, but I think it could work.

Answer (score 0):

> The IT industry has come a long way from the time it started. In not even a hundred years, we have seen dreams — like robots — come true. But we have also seen unexpected foes -- like viruses -- crop up.

Answer (score 0):

how about 'dystopian nightmare'

```
Dystopian: describes an imaginary society that is as dehumanizing and as unpleasant as possible.
```

[source: dystopian](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/dystopian)

while it might be that dystopian does not carry the 'unforseen' part of the request, it describes the negative effects of the viruses pretty well. Another possibility could be *unexpected dystopian nightmare*.

Comment: This might be an applicable answer, but it needs more fleshing out and support/justification.